# NgFor nested component not updating on @Input change

Tags: angular, typescript

I am populating a component (**ContactUpdatableItem**) within a **NgFor**:

```
 <section
        class="plContactCreation-listItem"
        *ngFor="let contact of contacts$ | async; index as idx"
      >
        <contact-updatable-item
          [contact]="contact" // This line will not work
        >
        </contact-updatable-item>
 </section>
```

The populated component listens to **Contact** changes via **@Input** setter:

```
export class ContactUpdatableItemComponent {
  @Input()
 set contact(contact: RestaurantLocationContactFragment) {
   this.bindContactData(contact);
 }
 get contact(): RestaurantLocationContactFragment {
    return this.modifiedContact$.value;
   }
}
```

**@Input** setter will be called only once when the component is loaded, and **never again**. 
If I change **ContactUpdatableItem** to be updated via **async**, it will work, and render correctly:

```
  <section
      class="plContactCreation-listItem"
      *ngFor="let contact of contacts$ | async; index as idx"
          >
            <contact-updatable-item
              [contact]="(contacts$ | async)[idx]" // This line will work
            >
            </contact-updatable-item>
 </section>
```

But I do not want to use this:

```
 [contact]="(contacts$ | async)[idx]"
```

How can I make my component render, and use a custom setter functionality without hacky tricks using the async and current index?

So my code will look like so:

```
 [contact]="contacts"
```

Comment: Did you try subscribing to your contacts in your ts file instead of doing using the async pipe? The only reason why your setter is not called is because the object reference is the same even if the properties inside have changed. I couldnt say why using the async pipe on each element works tho.

Comment: you can try to do somwhere in template `(contacts$ | async) as contacts` and use result `contacts` in loop and component param didnt test if that would help

Comment: @ukn Yes, you were right. The $contacts where cloned currently, yet the contact did not. It was the same object. Thank you so much.

Comment: @MCMatan So is your problem solved? As you mentioned, contacts$ returns cloned data every time your contacts$ emits new value then it should have 'contact' a new reference.

Comment: this is the exact problem I had, please explain what you did that worked. its not clear from the comments.

Answer (score 0):

This is the exact problem I had, @ukn 's comment on the question helped me too. writing it here as an answer to make it more visible and it should be accepted as the answer in my opinion:

Quoting ukn:

> The only reason why your setter is not called is because the object
> reference is the same even if the properties inside have changed.

meaning, even though the Subject emitted a new value the reference to the @Input setter remained the same and therefor was not updated, although the value inside changed.

the solution was to subscribe to the Subject from the .ts, save the value to an array in the .ts **by cloning it** (you can use JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj)) or something of that line), and iterate in ngFor over it (not using async).